# How can I create a curve shaped (C) UISlider with objective C

Tags: ios, uislider

I have been searching all over the internet for a solution to make a C shaped slider, I know how to customize a UISlider, but haven't been able to change the shape of the slider, any help?

Comment: please provide code what have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean with a "C shaped slider"? Could you please post an image of what you want to do? Also, show what you have tried and why it didn't work.

Comment: may be its curved

Comment: i know there already are stuff online but considering this as a duplicate is somewhat lame, because there are continuous updates and new libraries on the internet every single day especially with IOS, but i guess taking the easy way out is considering this as a duplicate:)
all i needed was to make a half circle slider, great to have some guidance or help, no need for criticism, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get the c shaped slider is to use 3rd party lib

[Cicle slider](https://github.com/caolsen/CircularSlider)

Using this lib and make angle change and you get C shaped slider. By default arc is 270 angle, change this property accordingly to get C shaped slider